# AJAX call in if condition not working as expected, blocks further else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, if-statement

I am a beginner to AJAX. I have used AJAX to check if a mobile number exists or not in MVC framework. I have a dialog box in which there is a form and one *Close* button. On that *Close* button click, I need to perform validations.

The code is as follows.

**View**

```
$( "#newCustAddClose" ).click(function() {
    //alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    var cname = $("#custname").val();
    var mno = $("#custmobilenumber").val();
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    var flag = 0;
    // alert(mno);
    if(cname == ""){
        alert( "Customer name is required!" );
        $( "#custname" ).focus();
    }
    else if(mno == ""){
        alert( "Mobile number is required!" );
        $( "#custmobilenumber" ).focus();
    }
    else if(!mno.match(phoneno)){
        alert('Please enter 10 digit mobile number.');
        $( "#custmobilenumber" ).focus();
    }
    else if(mno.match(phoneno)){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/sales/existmobile",
            type:"POST",
            data:{data: mno},
            success:function(response) {
                console.log('response',response); 
                successCallback(response);
            },
            error:function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#custdiv').dialog('close');
    }
});

function successCallback(responseObj){
    // Do something like read the response and show data
    //alert(JSON.stringify(responseObj)); // Only applicable to JSON response
    if (responseObj == 'false') {
        alert('Mobile number already exists!');
        $( "#custmobilenumber" ).focus();
    } 
}
```

When mobile number exists, it shows alert but if its not exists and I click on *Close* button its getting hang there. As all validations requirements are full filled it should close the dialog box. But it's not working.

I tried with `return successCallback(response);` and `return $.ajax({ ...` but that is also not working.

I am not getting what is going wrong. Please help and guide.

Comment: Use event.target.getAttribute() instead since these are not form elements

Comment: What does your browser devtools show - any errors on the console? Is the POST happening correctly?  What does the server respond? What format is the response, do you need to add the appropriate `dataType` to your AJAX?  Also note that your last `dialog()` call will never happen - if a phone number in the right format is entered, you will always end up in the AJAX block.  That code should probably move to your `successCallback()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$('#custdiv').dialog('close')` can never be reached.

This is because it's logically impossible for both `mno.match(phoneno)` and `!mno.match(phoneno)` to be false.  Once one of the earlier `else if` conditions returns true, none of the subsequent `else` statements will ever get looked at.

If you want the dialog to close when the ajax call responds `'true'`, I'd suggest moving the `$('#custdiv').dialog('close')` call into the `successCallback` function.

For example:

```
function successCallback(responseObj){
    if (responseObj == 'true') {
        $("#custdiv").dialog('close');
    } else {
        alert("Mobile number already exists!");
        $("#custmobilenumber").focus();
    } 
}
```